# EMMS doesn't seem to see anything from MPD

Tags: emms

I've set up MPD, and it's definitely running and indexing everything correctly. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/manual/Music-Player-Daemon.html) to set up EMMS to work with MPD, and after running `M-x emms-cache-set-from-mpd-all`, it indexed the right number of tracks, and connecting via `emms-player-connect` seems to work without error. However, when I call `M-x emms`, all I see is an empty window. What am I missing?

For reference, this is my config:

```
;;Media
(require 'emms-player-mpd)
(require 'emms-setup)
(emms-standard)
(emms-default-players)
(setq emms-player-mpd-server-name "localhost")
(setq emms-player-mpd-server-port "6600")
(add-to-list 'emms-player-list 'emms-player-mpd)
(add-to-list 'emms-info-functions 'emms-info-mpd)
```

Comment: If you try `(emms-all)` in place of `(emms-standard)`, does that fix it?

Comment: @BrianZ Nope - still get nothing in the window. I even tried ``(emms-devel)`` for good measure.

Comment: Personaly I used `mingus`, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `emms` is what you want. Try following the instructions in the emms manual carefully, ending up at `emms-smart-browse`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your MusicPD is configured to use absolute file names, you must set the `emms-player-mpd-music-directory` variable to the value of "music_directory" in your MusicPD configuration.

Add for example as follows:

```lisp
(setq emms-player-mpd-music-directory "~/Music/")
```