# EMMS and MPD configuration

Tags: emms

I've setup EMMS to use with MPD according to the manual with :

```
(use-package emms
  :config
    (require 'emms-setup)
    (require 'emms-player-mpd)
    (emms-all) ; don't change this to values you see on stackoverflow questions if you expect emms to work
    (setq emms-player-list '(emms-player-mpd))
    (add-to-list 'emms-info-functions 'emms-info-mpd)
    (add-to-list 'emms-player-list 'emms-player-mpd)

    ;; Socket is not supported
    (setq emms-player-mpd-server-name "localhost")
    (setq emms-player-mpd-server-port "6600")
    (setq emms-player-mpd-music-directory "/data/music")
  )
```

I can see the current playlist in MPD, play and pause. But I cannot add new files to it .
More precisely :

- `emms-cache-set-from-mpd-directory` displays `Dumping MusicPD data to cache...processing` but never finishes (even for a small folder).
- `emms-smart-browse` is never updated
- I can modify the playlist outside emacs with `ncmpcpp`.
- [the previous thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12662/emms-doesnt-seem-to-see-anything-from-mpd) was not helpful : mingus seems not maintained and broken

I'm using Doom emacs. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You have to run M-x `emms-cache-set-from-mpd-all` instead of `M-x emms-cache-set-from-mpd-directory`

You should add `(emms-player-mpd-connect)` to your Emms configuration if you want Emms to connect to mpd on startup.

Late answer, but might be useful to someone.